# PowerShell Username Generator - Add to File/Check Against

Tags: powershell, file, random

I am creating usernames as such: first 3 letters of the first name then 4 randomly generated numbers. Ryan Smith = `RYA4859`. I am getting the random number from this PowerShell command:

```
Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 10000
```

I need to know how to create a script that will add the username to a `.txt` file after it has been generated. I also want the script to first check the `.txt` file to see if the randomly generated number already already exists and if it does, generate a new 4 digit number that does not exist and then add that to the `.txt` file.

The flow should be:

- generate random 4 digit number
- check txt file if number exists
- if yes - generate new number
- if no - append file and add generated number to file

Comment: Load all lines of file as keys in hashtable, value can set to any value such as $true (but no need to ever check the value later).  `do{` Generate a new key `} while (` hashtable containskey `)`, add key to hashtable, overwrite file with all keys in hashtable.

Comment: i would ... [1] check for any username that starts with your 3 chars. [2] find the used numbers. [3] create a min..max range. [4] remove the used numbers. [5] grab a random number from the remaining number range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run a do...until loop that runs until the randomly generated number doesn't exist in your text file

```
$file = "C:\users.txt"
$userId = "RYA"

# get the contents of your text file
$existingUserList = Get-Content $file

do
{
    $userNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 10000

    # remove all alpha characters in the file, so only an array of numbers remains
    $userListReplaced = $existingUserList -replace "[^0-9]" , ''

# the loop runs until the randomly generated number is not in the array of numbers
} until (-not ($userNumber -in $userListReplaced))

# concatenates your user name with the random number
$user = $userId + $userNumber

# appends the concatenated username into the text file
$user | Out-File -FilePath $file -Append
```

Without the 3 character prefix

```
$file = "C:\users.txt"

# get the contents of your text file
$existingUserList = Get-Content $file

do
{
    $userNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 10000

    # remove all alpha characters in the file, so only an array of numbers remains
    $userListReplaced = $existingUserList -replace "[^0-9]" , ''

# the loop runs until the randomly generated number is not in the array of numbers
} until (-not ($userNumber -in $userListReplaced))
    
# appends the concatenated username into the text file
$userNumber| Out-File -FilePath $file -Append
```

Comment: This works, but how would I edit the code to remove output of R Y A ? I only need it to output the random 4 digit numbers?

Comment: Your specifications are strange but I've edited my answer without that output

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Hashtables in general will find keys in less time than finding a matching element in an unsorted array.  This difference in performance increases as the number of elements increase. While a binary search on a sorted arrays may come closer in performance, the sorting process itself can be be a major performance hit and add complexity to the code.

The main difference between the described version of the code in the comment on the question, and the following code, is that I'm appending the new user name to the file instead of over writing the file, and added a loop near the end to repeatedly ask if the code should continue.

```
function RandomDigits {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$DigitCount = 2
    )
    $RandString = [string](Get-Random -Minimum 100000 -Maximum 10000000)
    $RandString.Substring($RandString.Length-$DigitCount)
}
function GenUserName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Prefix
    )
    "$Prefix$(RandomDigits 4)"
}
function ReadAndMatchRegex {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Regex,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
        [string]$Prompt,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, Position = 2)]
        [string]$ErrMsg = "Incorrect, please enter needed info (Type 'exit' to exit)."
    )
    $FirstPass = $true
    do {
        if (-not $FirstPass) {
            Write-Host $ErrMsg -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host
        }
        $ReadText = Read-Host -Prompt $Prompt
        $ReadText = $ReadText.ToUpper()
        if($ReadText -eq 'exit') {exit}
        $FirstPass = $false
    } until ($ReadText -match $Regex)
    $ReadText
}
$Usernames = @{}
$UsernameFile = "$PSScriptRoot\Usernames.txt"
if(Test-Path -Path $UsernameFile -PathType Leaf) { 
    foreach($line in Get-Content $UsernameFile) { $Usernames[$Line]=$true }
}
do {
    Write-Host
    $UserPrefix = ReadAndMatchRegex '^[A-Z]{3}$' "Please enter 3 letters for user's ID"
    do {
        $NewUserName = GenUserName $UserPrefix
    } while ($Usernames.ContainsKey($NewUserName))
    $NewUserName | Out-File $UsernameFile -Append
    $UserNames[$NewUserName]=$true
    $UserNames.Keys
    $Continue = ReadAndMatchRegex '^(Y|y|YES|yes|Yes|N|n|NO|no|No)$' 'Continue?[Y/N]'
} while ($Continue -match '^(Y|y|YES|yes|Yes)$')
```

Comment: So this would generate a random 4 digit number and if said number already existed it would skip and generate a new one?

Comment: @Psychadelic23, yes.  The `do {$NewUserName = GenUserName $UserPrefix} while ($Usernames.ContainsKey($NewUserName))` will repeat until $NewUserName is not found in $Usernames.  With each repeat, $NewUserName gets new username from GenUserName.  GenUserName calls RandomDigits, creating a new user.  I tested this by changing `"$Prefix$(RandomDigits 4)"` to `"$Prefix$(RandomDigits 1)"`, this created usernames with only 1 digit.  Then repeatedly entered in the same 3 letters, producing all 10 possible usernames, and then getting caught in an infinite loop - as it couldn't find an unused name.